# How to disable jquery unobrusive validation on page load but keep on submit click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I'm my application, I have a form splitted on multiple pages, the viewmodel is posted accorss all pages (forward & backward).

All form methods are HTTP Post

```
Page 1 form is submitted to page 2 (Next)
Page 2 form is submitted to Page 3 (Next) or to Page 1 (Previous)
Page 3 form is submitted to Page 4 (Next) or to Page 2 (Previous)
....
```

My problem is that when the Page 2 is loaded, the form is validated and all required fields are in error state (normal, they are empty at this stage)

I'm searching a way to way to disable unobrusive validation on page load or  when the user click on the previous button (need to be a submit because hidden fields should be posted)

Validation shouldt occurs only when the user click on the "next" button.

In one word : I want to validte form only when user click on "Next" button.

thanks

Comment: You should look at using a tool such as JQuery Steps. Its a great library for achieving what your doing here.

Comment: Tested but not compatible with boostrap/jQuery/Unobrusive Validation. I use a lot of MVC 5 editor templates and I can't rewrite thes etemplate because they are used almost everywhere in my application.

Comment: You would probably get a quick answer if you could post some code. If you show some controller code (if you are doing a full postback) or javascript (if you are doing AJAX / Post) then I'll be able to help you.

Comment: JQuery Steps is 100% compatible with Unobtrsive validation, ive done it myself.

Comment: @br4d : code will not help (controller & view are about 1k lines), it's just simple form with a submit button, no Ajax, no additional scripts, Simple, Simple

Comment: @Derek : no, it's not working. my application is build from visual studio MVC 5 templates, just added bootstrap nuget. Once Jquery steps has been added, no more client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a css class of cancel to a submit button to suppress the client-side validation.

```
<input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: adding this on the previous button click disable the validation on submit:

```
 $("form").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
```

and to remove validation when 2nd posted form is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // don't know why but without this, don't work
        $('#form-inscription').validate().resetForm();

        var $form = $("#form-inscription");

        // get validator object
        var $validator = $form.validate();

        // get errors that were created using jQuery.validate.unobtrusive
        var $errors = $form.find(".field-validation-error");

        // this removes the validation messages
        $errors.each(function (e) {
            $(this).html('');
        });

        // clear errors from validation
        $validator.resetForm();
    });
```